# SQL Server User-Defined Data types calculated from properties

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to create a User-Defined Data Type, which is the concatenation of 3 properties, but 2 of which are not null, and one of which is. I have tried creating the user-defined data type, but it doesn't really let me, What I have is below:

```
USE <db>
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].<type> FROM [varchar](18) NOT NULL
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N<PropA>, @value=N'' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TYPE',@level1name=N<Type>
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N<PropB>, @value=N'' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TYPE',@level1name=N<Type>
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N<PropC>, @value=N'' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TYPE',@level1name=N<Type>
GO
```

My goal is for <type>  to be <PropA>_<PropB>_<PropC>

[image: ||Base Type|Calculation| |:-:|:-:|:-:| |<PropA>|Varchar(9)|| |<PropB>|Varchar(3)|| |<PropC>|Varchar(4)|| |<Type>|VarChar(18)|<PropA>_<PropB>_<PropC>|]

Comment: This doesn't should like you want a user defined `TYPE`, but a computed column. There is, in truth, really no reason to use scalar user defined `TYPE`s, also known as Alias Types, as they really don't add any additional functionality, and actually just make things harder in the future. If, for example, you have tables that use an alias `TYPE` and you ever need to increase the size of that `TYPE`, you'll be in for a world of hurt.

Comment: What's your actual end goal?   Store the computation somewhere?   User defined types are really about being able to pass volumes of tabular data into stored procedures.   You have everything you need in the first three properties to produce the computed column.

Comment: @ Lamu, This is a constant type which will never change, it already has padding, the number of for property A is currently at 5, and this is after 15-20 years. (I just added extra padding.)

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor, I am not the best at explaining myself,  but the best I can explain it is that, I will be programming a lot of forms for this, and for the sake of preventing user error(overriding, repetitive entry), would like to bury the value out of reach. but then only I would be able to use it.

Comment: T-SQL's user-defined types are unfortunately mostly useless. They serve only as aliases and typically confuse more than they enforce consistency. You certainly cannot implement logic of the kind sketched above as a type. You will unfortunately have to accept that the kind of consistency or reliability you're after is not something T-SQL caters to. Use computed columns, views, stored procedures or whatever your client tool of choice is for generating code, possibly in combination with [database projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/how-to-create-a-new-database-project).

Comment: In this particular case, it looks like you're violating normalization rules to begin with, by insisting on stuffing three separate pieces of data into one. This is not always wrong, and schemas can't always be changed, but you may still consider making these three columns of a table instead, and referencing to that table with foreign keys where you need the combination.

Comment: thank you  @JeroenMostert, I was trying to condense it kind of like a nested table in power query, but maybe I can link tables to a record instead.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially there is no way to do this.

Best Solution:
Computed Column